# Fluxbox closing as soon as is opened on LXDE

Tags: linux, configuration, configuration-files, archlinux, window-managers

I'm unable to get fluxbox working together with LXDE, I configured fluxbox to be its window manager, but fluxbox closes as soon as its launched (I can see fluxbox environment for a second) and LXDE goes back to its default window manager.

My xinitrc file is pretty standard I just included at the bottom

```
exec startlxde
exec startfluxbox
```

Also modified the `~/.config/lxsession/LXDE/desktop.conf` file to set fluxbox as the window manager

```
window_manager=fluxbox
```

Any pointers to get them working together?

Comment: You can't `exec` two things. `exec` replaces the current process with a new process. That `exec fluxbox` line is almost certainly doing nothing for you. Are you sure fluxbox is actually crashing? Does it have logs somewhere? What do you mean you see the "fluxbox environment for a second"?

Comment: I dont think any logs are generated, what I mean is that it seems that the window manager environment for fluxbox loads for a couple of seconds then the display refreshes and it goes back to the default window manager from LXDE. I know how fluxbox environment looks because if I add it before startlxde on the xinitrc file I can work with it without closing but then I am pretty much running only with a windows manager and no desktop environment.

Comment: That sounds more like LXDE is starting its own window manager and forcing fluxbox to exit to me... though maybe not. You have `[Session]\nwindow_manager=fluxbox` in your `desktop.conf` file? If you just start fluxbox in your `.xinitrc` it works correctly? Does using `window_manager=startfluxbox` do anything different?

Comment: Yes, if I place startfluxbox on the xinitrc file before startlxde fluxbox loads fine but then I have no LXDE. I tried changing window_manager to startfluxbox and I have the same behavior fluxbox closing. By the way I noticed that within LXDE gui you can change the window manager, I did change to fluxbox but I get the same behavior, fluxbox runs for a second then its back to the default window manager.

Comment: That from-the-gui behavior is interesting. Can you write a wrapper script for fluxbox that catches the output and return code to a file and use that as window manager and see what happens? Something like `#!/bin/bash\nfluxbox "$@" &>/tmp/fluxbox.start; echo "exited: $?" >> /tmp/fluxbox.start` perhaps?